# Linux rs232 reading - Select call seems to block until data is not being sent anymore

Tags: c, linux, serial-port

I'm working on debugging some latency issues I'm seeing with a select call in my application. I'm opening up my rs232 file handle with the following flags:

```
rs232_fd = open("/dev/ttys3", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY | O_EXCL);
```

and trying a select call as follows:

```
struct timeval tv;
fd_set set;

FD_ZERO(&set);
FD_SET(rs232_fd, &set);

tv.tv_sec = 1;
tv.tv_usec = 500000;

select(rs232_fd+1, &set, NULL, NULL, &tv)
```

I have an embedded device writing to the serial port sending ~10kB blocks at 115200 baud. I'd like to start processing the data as it comes in, but what I'm seeing is that the select call is blocking for nearly a second which is about the time it takes for the device to finish sending all the data. Not sure if the timing is a coincidence or not.

It's my understanding that select should unblock as soon as there is data to read on the file descriptor, is that the case? Am I missing some flags in my open? Are there some other settings I need to make sure I have configured? Are there any issues with reading to a file descriptor while there's data being written to it?

Comment: You probably don't even need to use **select()** (or **inotify()**) if you're only (noncanonical or raw?) reading from one serial port.

Answer (score 0):

Select is known to have issues. And its efficiency is still a question. You can give inotify a try.